# CUDA Illegal memory access with possibly 'insufficient' shared memory

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I have a simple CUDA kernel that can do vector accumulation by basic reduction. I am scaling it up to be able to handle larger data by splitting it across multiple blocks. However, my assumption about allocating an appropriate amount of shared memory to be used by the kernel is failing with illegal memory access. It goes away when I increase this limit, but I want to know why.
Here is the code that I am talking about:

CORE KERNEL:

```
    __global__ static
    void vec_add(int *buffer,
               int numElem,    //  The actual number of elements
               int numIntermediates)   //  The next power of two of numElem
    {
        extern __shared__ unsigned int interim[];

        int index = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

        //  Copy global intermediate values into shared memory.
        interim[threadIdx.x] =
          (index < numElem) ? buffer[index] : 0;

        __syncthreads();

        //  numIntermediates2 *must* be a power of two!
        for (unsigned int s = numIntermediates / 2; s > 0; s >>= 1) {
            if (threadIdx.x < s) {
                interim[threadIdx.x] += interim[threadIdx.x + s];
            }
            __syncthreads();
        }

        if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
            buffer[blockIdx.x] = interim[0];
        }
    }
```

And this is the caller:

```
void accumulate (int* buffer, int numElem)
{
    unsigned int numReductionThreads =
      nextPowerOfTwo(numElem); // A routine to return the next higher power of 2.

    const unsigned int maxThreadsPerBlock = 1024;  // deviceProp.maxThreadsPerBlock

    unsigned int numThreadsPerBlock, numReductionBlocks, reductionBlockSharedDataSize;

    while (numReductionThreads > 1) {

        numThreadsPerBlock = numReductionThreads < maxThreadsPerBlock ?           
            numReductionThreads : maxThreadsPerBlock;

        numReductionBlocks = (numReductionThreads + numThreadsPerBlock - 1) / numThreadsPerBlock;

        reductionBlockSharedDataSize = numThreadsPerBlock * sizeof(unsigned int);

        vec_add <<< numReductionBlocks, numThreadsPerBlock, reductionBlockSharedDataSize >>>
            (buffer, numElem, numReductionThreads);

        numReductionThreads = nextPowerOfTwo(numReductionBlocks);
    }

}
```

I tried this code with a sample set of 1152 elements on my GPU with the following configuration:
Type: Quadro 600
MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
MaxSharedMemory: 48KB

OUTPUT:

```
Loop 1: numElem = 1152, numReductionThreads = 2048, numReductionBlocks = 2, numThreadsPerBlock = 1024, reductionBlockSharedDataSize = 4096
Loop 2: numElem = 1152, numReductionThreads = 2, numReductionBlocks = 1, numThreadsPerBlock = 2, reductionBlockSharedDataSize = 8
CUDA Error 77: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

Suspecting that my 'interim' shared memory was causing illegal memory access, I arbitrarily increased the shared memory by two times in the following line:

```
reductionBlockSharedDataSize = 2 * numThreadsPerBlock * sizeof(unsigned int);
```

And my kernel started working fine!

What I do not understand is - why I had to provide this extra shared memory to make my problem go away (temporarily).

As a further experiment to check this magic number I ran my code with a much larger data-set with 6912 points. This time, even 2X or 4X didn't help me.

```
Loop 1: numElem = 6912, numReductionThreads = 8192, numReductionBlocks = 8, numThreadsPerBlock = 1024, reductionBlockSharedDataSize = 16384

Loop 2: numElem = 6912, numReductionThreads = 8, numReductionBlocks = 1, numThreadsPerBlock = 8, reductionBlockSharedDataSize = 128
CUDA Error 77: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

But the problem again went away when I increased the shared memory size by 8X.

Of course, I cannot be arbitrarily picking this scaling factor for larger and larger data-sets because I will soon run out of the 48KB shared memory limit. So I want to know a legitimate way of fixing my issue.

Comment: Did you calculate the largest index in you for loop? From a quick look I think the math is the following: `numIntermediates = 2048` (the next power of 2 for 1152), then `s = 1024` and `threadIdx.x < s` means max. `threadIdx.x = 1023`. Thus, the largest index is 2047, however you allocate only memory for 1024 ints.

Comment: Thanks @havogt : You pointed out the source of the error!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @havogt for pointing out the out-of-index access.
The issue was that I was using the wrong argument as numIntermediates to the vec_add method. The intention was for the kernel to operate on exactly the same number of data points as the number of threads, which should have been 1024 all the time.
I fixed it by using numThreadsPerBlock as the argument:

```
vec_add <<< numReductionBlocks, numThreadsPerBlock, reductionBlockSharedDataSize >>>
        (buffer, numElem, numThreadsPerBlock);
```